# How to write float values to a text file in Java

Tags: java, netbeans, file-io, floating-point, netbeans-7

I am reading files from a GRD file:

```
File stockInputFile = new File("C://MAX.GRD");
```

I want to write them to a text file:

```
File StockOutputFile = new File("C://StockOut.txt");
```

Am getting some Korean letters. Can you please help me in coding?
Actually I want to store them as float numbers into a text file .. I am able to do the same with C.

```
fin = fopen("D:\\DailyT\\MeanT\\MEAN.GRD","rb");   // Input file
fout = fopen("D:\\DailyT\\MEAN.TXT","w");     // Output file
fread(&t,sizeof(t),1,fin) ;

for(i=0 ; i < 32 ; i++)
{  
    fprintf(fout,"\n") ;
    for(j=0 ; j < 35 ; j++)
        fprintf(fout,"%6.2f",t[i][j]);
}
```

Comment: How exactly can Korean letters occur in a file that is supposed to contain float values? Please explain. Your question is at present meaningless.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, writing to a file goes like this:

```
import java.io.*;
class FileWrite 
{
 public static void main(String args[])
 {
  try{
   // Create file 
   FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter("out.txt");
   BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);
   out.write("Hello Java");

   //Close the output stream
   out.close();
  } catch (Exception e) {
   System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
  }
 }
}
```

See Google to get more tutorials about "java write to file" and "java read from file". Also please update your question once you have actually tried something and met with some difficulty.

Comment: i did the same , i faced problem when am trying to write to a file what ever i read from a grid file... Am trying to write float values to the text file

Comment: Then show your Java code ... someone already asked you to do that an hour ago.